# My app crashes when i connect to firebase database

Tags: java, android, json, firebase-realtime-database, crash

I uploaded a json file to firebase database. Size of file is 3mb and my application crashes when I connect to firebase from the application

logcat :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:151)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
                                                                    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

09-04 15:56:51.405 26584-26714/com.tako.dopingeng E/RunLoop: Firebase Database encountered an OutOfMemoryError. You may need to reduce the amount of data you are syncing to the client (e.g. by using queries or syncing a deeper path). See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data#best_practices_for_data_structure and https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#filtering_data
                                                             java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: [memory exhausted]
                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Please include some of the initialization code of the firebase instance, pretty hard to tell what's going on without that.

Comment: The message is saying what you need to do: 

> You may need to reduce the amount of data you are syncing to the client (e.g. by using queries or syncing a deeper path).

Comment: Then what can i do ?

Comment: ` public  void getWords() {


        try {
            DatabaseReference dfr = db.getReference().child("tako").child("words");
            dfr.keepSynced(true);
            dfr.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                   
                    if(dataSnapshot.exists())
                    {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                   

                    }
                }

            `